# Pass NSString values from one ViewController to Another using Notifications?

Tags: ios, nsnotificationcenter, nsnotification

How can I pass NSString values from `ViewController1` to `ViewController2` by using notifications in iOS? I have tried:

**ViewController1**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
     [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(incomingNotification:) name:@"test" object:nil];

 }
    - (void) incomingNotification:(NSNotification *)notification{
        NSString *theString = [notification object];
        NSLog(@"theString value=%@",theString);
    }
```

**ViewController2**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
     NSString *myString=@"testing";
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"test" object: myString];
}
```

It works fine while am going to ViewController2.

But I want to send values from `ViewController1` to `ViewController2` using these notifications. Is it possible. How?

Comment: Why? You most likely shouldn't be using notifications. And when do you want to send these *messages*?

Comment: For learning purpose i need to know notifications.Thats why am using notifications.its possible or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You  can use it by initializing ViewController2 in ViewController1's on button click event..Steps to invoke,
 1.Create on method (say like notifRegister) in ViewController2,which initialize notification to receive dictionary value.
 2.On button click event init ViewController2 and call method notifRegister
 3.Then post notification in ViewController1.

Example:

```
 - (IBAction)navigation:(id)sender {

    ViewController1 *vc=  [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController2"];
    [vc notifRegister];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:(UIViewController*)vc animated:YES];

    NSDictionary *name=[[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Tommy",@"name",nil];
      [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"TextChanged" object:name];
}
```

On ViewController2:

```
    -(void)notifRegister
{

 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(reloadLabel:) name:@"TextChanged"object:nil];

}
-(void)reloadLabel:(NSNotification*)sender
{
    NSLog(@"reload label called %@",sender.object);

    self.labelName=[sender.object objectForKey:@"name"];
}
```

Here self.labelName is an NSString object...

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not necessary to call a invisible viewController to send notification. You can pass your values as below:

If you use storyboard, you can get ViewController2 in ViewController1's method `prepareForSegue`, so you can pass your reference here.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    var targetViewController = segue.destinationViewController as UIViewController
}
```

If your manually create the second ViewController and use `presentViewController`, just pass your reference when initializing your ViewController2.

---

If you insist to use notification. Set view2 as a notification sender and view1 as a receiver with another notification.

Comment: How Set view2 as a notification sender and view1 as a receiver with another notification?

Comment: don't use the same notification name

Comment: And don't put `postNotificationName` method in the `viewDidLoad` method cause the receiver has not been created yet.

Answer (score 0):

You get an NSNotification object passed to your function.

Put your strings or other objects in the dictionary

```
NSDictionary* userInfo = @{@"completionHandler" : completionHandler,
                           @"myStringIdentifier" : myString};

NSNotificationCenter* nc = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
[nc postNotificationName:@"myNotification" object:self userInfo:userInfo];


[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(receiveNotification:) name:@"UIKeyboardWillHideNotification" object:nil];

-(void) receiveNotification:(NSNotification*)notification
{
    if ([notification.name isEqualToString:@"MyNotification"])
    {
       NSDictionary* userInfo = notification.userInfo;
       ... do dictionary stuff
    }
}
```

This is a question which has been asked before search for userinfo and NSNotification for more examples

Comment: Thank you @Ryan Heitner . But I need to know which ViewController i have put this code.please tell clearly Ryan Heitner

Comment: An NSNotifcation can be put into any object.You send a notification from one object and you could receive with an observer it in one or many other places. Try a tutorial such as http://www.devfright.com/nsnotificationcenter-tutorial/ to get a better understanding. Before you post a question you should try do as much homework as possible to avoid being downvoted

Answer (score 0):

As per the doc, yes it's possible. But you should read the doc first (see [NSNotificationCenter class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSNotificationCenter)).

The method you should look at is

```
- (void)postNotificationName:(NSString *)notificationName
                  object:(id)notificationSender
                userInfo:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
```

where

`notificationName` is the notification you want to post. The `notificationSender` is the object that want to post the notification and `userInfo` is the info you want to pass with the notification.

So, if you want to pass a notification from `ViewController2` to `ViewController1` (or viceversa).

```
// ViewController1

- (void)viewDidLoad {
     [super viewDidLoad];

     [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(incomingNotification:) name:@"myNotificationName" object:nil];
}

- (void) incomingNotification:(NSNotification *)notification {

    NSDictionary *userInfo = notification.userInfo;

    NSString *theString = userInfo[@"stringKey"]; // Here you retrieve the passed string from ViewController2 to ViewController1
    NSLog(@"%@",theString);
}

// ViewController2

// Suppose you have an action set up for a specific button
- (IBAction)buttonTapped {
    NSDictionary *userInfo = @{@"stringKey": @"stringPassed"};
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"myNotificationName" object:self userInfo:userInfo];
}
```

Here I would highlight two main things.

1. Both controllers should be "valid". In other words they should be allocated in memory and presented somewhere.
2. When you add an observer you should also remove it.

**Update 1**

In this case you are passing a string from `UIViewController2` to `UIViewController1`. Just switch the code you are using and you will be able to pass the same string from `ViewController1` to `ViewController2`.

My question: what's your goal?

Comment: okay how can i get NSString values in viewcontroller2 @flexaddicted.

Comment: @Tabi see the comments. In this case you are passing from view controller 2 to view controller 1.

Answer (score 0):

this will work...

in ViewController 2

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"test" object:self userInfo:@{@"stringValue": myString}];
```

in ViewController 1

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
     [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(incomingNotification:) name:@"test" object:nil];

}
- (void) incomingNotification:(NSNotification *)notification{

    NSString *theString = notification.userInfo[@"stringValue"] ;

    NSLog(@"theString value=%@",theString);
}
```